# Exception Handling Block - Manually registering the ExceptionManager class

Tags: exception, unity-container, enterprise-library

Is it possible to register the abstract ExceptionManager type with it's concrete implementation ExceptionManagerImpl ?

The default relies on Unity container, and I am already using Windsor so I would like to register the Exception Handling Block components on Windsor manually.

Comment: Trying to discover the ExceptionManagerImpl dependencies I run into troubles because it seems Unity passes .ctor dependencies via Expressions. I put a question for that here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955813/unity-container-get-value-from-parametervalue-expression

Comment: All my effort so far is described here http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2011/05/error-management-is-sometimes-exceptionally-difficult.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You will need to build a Windsor configurator for EntLib. We touch on this in the [Architectural Refactoring overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2009/06/25/enterprise-library-5-0-architectural-refactoring-complete.aspx).

Comment: I already built a Windsor configurator for EntLib, however I have to manually register any components containing ConstructorParameters in TypeRegistration (have a look at my progress so far, http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2011/05/error-management-is-sometimes-exceptionally-difficult.html)

Comment: @Nikos, ah, ok. I cannot look at your log now - I am in the final week of a release. Will try to review it at the end of next week. You may want to post your question on the entlib.codeplex.com forum. There might be someone else who has already built a Windsor configurator who'll be able to respond sooner. I've seen one for Autofac.

Comment: I got it working with Windsor :-) I put everything here: https://github.com/moodmosaic/WindsorContainerConfigurator I still have a lot of work to do. It is heavily based on UnityContainerConfigurator implementation.

Comment: Excellent, Nikos. Consider adding your configurator to EntLibContrib.codeplex.com.

Comment: Yes, I will do it (I sent you a message on EntLibContrib for the Sign Up Process).